# Example of a case that shows that a Hilbert lattice of infinite dimension is not modular.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, vector-lattices

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space. Let $C(H)$ be the set of closed 
subspaces of the Hilbert space $H$. 

Let $\le$ be the inclusion $\subseteq$. For $a,b \in C(H)$ define

- $a^\perp$ as the othogonal closed space of $a$,
- $a\wedge b =  a \cap b $,
- $a \vee b= \{$  the smallest closed subspace that contains  $a$ and $b \}$.

Using these definitions, $C(H)$ is an orthomodular lattice, and it will be modular if and only if $H$ has finite dimension.

*N.B.* A lattice $\mathcal L$ is said to be modular iff
$$\forall a,b \in \mathcal L: a\le b \quad\Rightarrow \quad\forall c \in \mathcal{L}: a \vee (c \wedge b) = (a \vee c) \wedge b.$$

> I'd like help with finding an example of three closed subspaces $a, b, c$ of an infinite dimensional Hilbert space $H$ such that $a\le b$ doesn't imply  $a \vee (c \wedge b) = (a \vee c) \wedge b $.

Comment: You can find an example in Redei's *Quantum logic in Algebraic Approach*, Proposition 4.4, pg. 49. 
More specifically, let $(e_n)$ be an orthonormal basis of $H$,  $a>1$ and define a sequence $(\xi_n)$ as $\xi_n=e_{2n}+a^{-n}e_1+a^{-2n}e_{2n+1}$. Then set 
$F=[\xi_n: n\in \mathbb{N}]$,  $G=[e_1, \xi_n: n\in \mathbb{N}]$ and $H=[e_{2n}: n\in\mathbb{N}].$